# CSS transition-property does not select font-size inside VScode

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Font-size is white, as can be seen in the picture below. I'm assuming the transition property doesn't select font-size because it does not recognize it inside VScode as a selectable property. On an online editor the transition-property: font-size; rule works, so I am wondering is this VScode fault, or am I writing something wrongly. I would very much like for somebody to explain to me what is it that I am doing wrongly, if that's the case. Thank you!

[css code][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftFG4.png*strong text*

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="heading">animacija</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `font-size` in your VS code is looking white because your VS code theme is different.
2. `transition` property doesn't work if you are running it on mozilla firefox or any other browser except chrome. In that case, you need to specify it in your css like below:

```css
body .heading {
    font-size: 20px;   
    color: aqua;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 2s;
       -moz-transition: font-size 2s;
         -o-transition: font-size 2s;
            transition: font-size 2s;
}

.heading:hover {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="heading">animacija</h1>
</body>
</html>
```